# Why ListView.getChildAt() is returning null in android

Tags: android, listview

I have two lists `listArray` and `itemStateList`.

`listArray` is containing text to display in `ListView` and `itemStateList` is containing color names to set the background in the `ListView`. but `listView.getChildAt(i)` is always returning `null`.

I find some solution here on StackOverflow stating to use `listView.getAdapter().getView(i)` instead. but there was no detail about, why to use `listView.getAdapter()` and why `listView.getChildAt()` is not working. and also just want to know when to use `listView.getChildAt()`.

Here is the code..

```
public void createAndSetAdapter(){

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    for(int i = 0; i < listArray.size(); i++){
        switch (itemStateList.get(i)){
            case "Green_color":
                listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AAFF7F"));
                break;
            case "red_color":
                listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAAAA"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `listArray` in `for` loop and `itemStateList` in `switch` both are different `list`

Comment: `for` loop is to loop equal to size of `listArray`. and `switch` is checking what color is to set in `ListView` according to `itemStateList`.

Comment: why -1, my code is working fine only wanted to know the difference between `getChildAt()` and `getAdapter().getView()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listView.getChildAt(i) works where 0 is the very first visible row and (n-1) is the last visible row (where n is the number of visible views you see).

Try this:

```
listView.getChildAt(positionOfChildYouWantGet - f_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

Difference between using getChildAt and listAdapter.getView is that :

The getChildAt is not a method special to a ListView. It is implemented for each ViewGroup (View that can have children).

When your ListView is created, it has no children. Calling its adapter's getView method doesn't change that fact, it doesn't add any children.

Only when your Activity's content gets measured and laid-out, the ListView will start creating child views by calling its adapter's getView method repeatedly and adding the returned Views to its own list of children. Only after that, ListView.getChildAt(x) could return some non-null value.

The ListAdapter.getView method returns brand new Views (or just returns the recycled View) on behalf of ListView/GridView/etc. Your code should never call ListAdapter.getView itself (unless you do a Unit test).

ListView.getChildAt returns an already created View (created earlier by ListAdapter.getView on behalf of the ListView) Note that your ListAdpater may define many many list items (the value returned by getCount), but the ListView hosting the adapter will never have more children than can be visible at any given time on the screen. I.e. your ListAdapter may deal with 1000 list-items, but your ListView will never have more than 6 child Views (depending on size of screen and listview-item, of course).